# Having problems accessing Apache Webserver from Webmin

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, webmin

I'm running apache on AMI, and I am unable to start the server through webmin. When I try, I get:

```
Failed to start apache : Apache does not appear to be running : 
[Wed Sep 07 20:53:22.937284 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 9985] AH01232: suEXEC >mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed Sep 07 20:53:22.958565 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 9986] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Sep 07 20:53:22.959164 2016] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 9986] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Wed Sep 07 20:53:22.983021 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 9986] AH00163: Apache/2.4.23 (Amazon) PHP/5.6.24 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Sep 07 20:53:22.983041 2016] [core:notice] [pid 9986] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd'
```

This is my first time setting up a site on AWS, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The logs above show that the server started.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure whether Apache is running or not by issuing the below command:

ps ax | grep httpd | grep -v grep

or try to visit your index.html page.

Also, just for your reference, webmin was dropped by Ubuntu https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WebMin